# How to use nested lookup with Lightning RecordViewForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components

What is the "proper" way of displaying nested lookup data in a lightning component? For example, Say I had a `Contact` object, which had a lookup field for an `OCampaign (OCampaign__c)` object, which had a lookup field for a `Employer (Employer__c)` object. If I want to display the employer's name while the component's record is the Contact, how would one go about doing that? I've tried the following

```
<lightning:recordViewForm
      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
      objectApiName="Contact"
>
      <lightning:messages />
      <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
      <lightning:outputField fieldName="OCampaign__c" />
      <lightning:outputField fieldName="OCampaign__c.Name" /> // Doesn't work, breaks with an error similar to the one below.
      <lightning:outputField fieldName="OCampaign__c.Employer__c.Name" /> // Doesn't work. same as above, but what I actually want
      <lightning:outputField fieldName="OCampaign__r" /> // Error: Field [OCampaign__r] was not found
      <lightning:outputField fieldName="OCampaign__r.Name" /> // Error: Field [OCampaign__r.Name] was not found
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

But, as noted, it doesn't work because it encounters an exception.

```
// NOTE: formatted for readability

Exception encountered in value provider: TransportResponse {
    body: {
        errorCode: "INVALID_FIELD",
        message: "INVALID_FIELD: 
            EmailBouncedReason, Name, SystemModstamp, Campaign__c.Name, Id, PhotoUrl,
                                      ^
            ERROR at Row:1:Column:944
            Didn't understand relationship 'OCampaign__c' in field path.
            If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name.
            Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."
    }
}
```

Do I need to make a server-side controller to fetch the data?

Comment: What is the error message? Please **[edit]** your post to include it *verbatim*.

Comment: Sorry about that. Error added.

Answer (score 0):

Relationship Names don't work the way you have it in your query.

**Incorrect**

```
Campaign__c.Name
```

**Correct**

```
Campaign__r.Name
```

---

Generally, you can get the relationship name of a lookup field by either inspecting the UI (where you may have to some extrapolation to figure out namespace and suffix), or via anonymous script such as the below:

```
String relationshipName = MyObject__c.Campaign__c.getDescribe().getRelationshipName();
system.debug(relationshipName);
```

Ostensibly, that would output `Campaign__r`, which you would then use to do your query join.

Comment: Hey Adrian, Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't mention it in my question, but I'm not using the server-side SOQL to get the data, rather, I'm using the RecordViewForm component. Do I need to use a server-side controller (so I could have control over the query) for fetching the relations?